# Как скрыть базу данных от лишних глаз?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Есть приложение на Android, оно использует базу данных. В ней хранятся данные, которые пользователь не должен видеть (различные коды). Однако при открытии приложения в проводнике (ES проводник) можно запросто найти эту базу данных. Я скопировал ее в корневую папку и переместил на комп через USB. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как скрыть эту базу данных, т.к. она ни в коем случае не должна попасть "не в те руки".

Comment: Храните её не на телефоне, а на сервере.

Comment: Была такая мысль, но нужно именно локальную БД.

Comment: Тогда , думаю, никак.Можно использовать кучу разных костылей но тот, кому она понадобится, доберется до нее без проблем в любом случае.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте внутреннее (internal) хранилище телефона.
Как здесь написано: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files

> Internal storage is best when you want to be sure that neither the user nor other apps can access your files.

Внутренне хранилище приложения представлено двумя папками: `getFilesDir()` и `getCacheDir()`. Вторая предназначена для временных файлов, система может ее сама чистить при нехватке места.

Примеры: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files/internal

Comment: Думаю, стоит упомянуть, что при наличии root доступа эти файлы доступны через проводник. В таком случае можно ещё использовать костыль запароливания БД, правда, т.к. пароль надо хранить где-то, процесс доступа к БД усложнится лишь на один шаг - вскрытие исходников и поиск там пароля.